# reduceByKey doesn't work in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have the following code snippet in which the reduceByKey doesn't seem to work.

```
val myKafkaMessageStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams)
)

myKafkaMessageStream
  .foreachRDD { rdd => 
    val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
    val myIter = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (i, iter) =>
      val offset = offsetRanges(i)
      iter.map(item => {
        (offset.fromOffset, offset.untilOffset, offset.topic, offset.partition, item)
      })
    }

    val myRDD = myIter.filter( (<filter_condition>) ).map(row => {
      //Process row

      ((field1, field2, field3) , (field4, field5))
    })

    val result = myRDD.reduceByKey((a,b) => (a._1+b._1, a._2+b._2))

    result.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
      //I don't get the reduced result here
      val connection = createNewConnection()
      partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
      connection.close()
    }        
  }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is very little detail here. Can you reduce this to the core example (with constant stream or queue stream)? What does it mean: _doesn't seem to work_? Throws an exception? Doesn't group records? If the former one are you sure that records can be compared way (provide useful hash / equality)?

Comment: Why would you expect fromOffset, untilOffset and topic to create a proper key to reduce by?

Comment: @LostInOverflow Sorry for the lack of clarity. When I do myRDD.foreach(println), I see the contents. But when I do result.foreach(println) I don't see the contents... So there are no errors... but I get empty results

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov So, I am trying to store the fromOffset and untilOffset in database after processing the records. This way I know the latest offset that got processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a streaming situation, it makes more sense to me to use `reduceByKeyAndWindow` which does what you're looking for, but over a specific time frame.

```
// Reduce last 30 seconds of data, every 10 seconds
val windowedWordCounts = pairs.reduceByKeyAndWindow((a:Int,b:Int) => (a + b), Seconds(30), Seconds(10))
```

"When called on a DStream of (K, V) pairs, returns a new DStream of (K, V) pairs where the values for each key are aggregated using the given reduce function func over batches in a sliding window. Note: By default, this uses Spark's default number of parallel tasks (2 for local mode, and in cluster mode the number is determined by the config property spark.default.parallelism) to do the grouping. You can pass an optional numTasks argument to set a different number of tasks."

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html